Unexpected result from MemberQ
MMA 14.0
Can somebody explain why the following evaluates to False:
MemberQ[1/y[x], y, Infinity]

False


Use MemberQ[1/y[x], y[_], Heads -> True] or MemberQ[1/y[x], y[_]] or MemberQ[1/y[x], _y].

Thank you for the workaround.

For this sort of test, I might use Not[FreeQ[expr, y]]. But it depends. It's not the same as @Domen's MemberQ[expr, _y]. Of course, they give the same result on expr = 1/y[x]. But not when expr = 1/y. So it depends on what is desired and what inputs are possible.

The FullFormof 1/y[x] is Power[y[x],-1]
Let's see what elements MemberQ say are present
# -> MemberQ[1/y[x], #, Infinity] & /@ {x, y, 1, -1, Power} 


{x->True,y->False,1->False,-1->True,Power->False}


Both Power and y are not elements, but Heads
As pointed out by @Domen, using the option Heads -> True will include the Heads in the search

# -> MemberQ[1/y[x], #, Infinity, Heads -> True] & /@ {x, y, 1, -1, 
  Power} 


{x->True,y->True,1->False,-1->True,Power->True} 



Thanks a lot for pointing out that this is a question of "Head"
